# Why is my app not displaying recorded message?

Tags: java, android, debugging

So, I am creating an AI music player app. Everything seems fine but whenever I give it some voice command, it does not display the required message.

I have tried using different emulators and using different android versions. None of those worked.

```
package com.learning.intelligentmusicplayer;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RelativeLayout parentRelativeLayout;
    private SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer;
    private Intent speechRecogniserIntent;
    private String keeper="";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        checkVoiceCommandPermission();
        parentRelativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.parentRelativeLayout);

        speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(MainActivity.this);
        speechRecogniserIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        speechRecogniserIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM );
        speechRecogniserIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());

        speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRmsChanged(float v) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onBufferReceived(byte[] bytes) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onEndOfSpeech() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int i) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResults(Bundle bundle) {
                ArrayList<String> matchesFound = bundle.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
                if(matchesFound!=null)
                {
                    keeper = matchesFound.get(0);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Result = "+keeper, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPartialResults(Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onEvent(int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }
        });

        parentRelativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                switch(motionEvent.getAction())
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        speechRecognizer.startListening(speechRecogniserIntent);
                        keeper="";
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        speechRecognizer.stopListening();
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }



    private void checkVoiceCommandPermission()
    {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            if(!(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package: "+getPackageName()));
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is no error message. I hear the beep sound for recording message but it does not display the message on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading Google voice assistant fixed my problem!